# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard - Does it lock source tables?

Tags: sql-server

Question is as asked.  When I run the Import and Export Wizard to pull data from one database to another does it put a lock on the source table when performing the copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's still performing a `SELECT` on the object like any other query would. Just because you're using the import/export wizard doesn't change how the underlying SQL works.

Comment: Why would it not use `WITH (NOLOCK)` to make for safer export/imports?

Comment: That isn't what `WITH (NOLOCK)` does @whoisearth. I'd actually suggest using that table hint would be a really bad idea for an import/export process.